# Application go fullscreen at startup

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, fullscreen

Since MacOSX Lion, Cocoa supports a new fullscreen feature.
I implement it in my application window thanks to the following instruction from my application delegate:

```
[_window setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary];
```

Is it possible to go to this presentation at startup?

Thanks for help!

Edit: I still want the fullscreen menu bar feature (which doesn't work with *enterFullscreenMode:withOptions:*

Answer (score 2):

You can make window's view full screen like this:

```
[self enterFullScreenMode:[NSScreen mainScreen] withOptions:nil];
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seems to be the same behavior than when clicking on the fullscreen button: when moving the mouse at the top of the screen the menu doesn't show down...

Comment: @tinmaru take a look at this tutorial: http://www.cocoacrumbs.com/blog/?p=128. Also it has example project at the bottom of the page. I think now Your problem will be solved. Let me know tinmaru.